# How to avoid app from crashing in synchronous request

Tags: objective-c, httpurlconnection

I am posting some JSON data to a server using JSONKit.

Before posting the data, I am checking the internet connection.

But if the internet connection is lost after sending request, after this line:

```
NSData *receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                             returningResponse:&response
                                                         error:&error];
```

my app crashes.

I don't want to use asynchronous method here.

Is there any particular way, where I can show an alert rather than having my app crash in this situation?

Comment: What is the reason of crash?

Comment: It might help to explain what crash you're getting and where. The line of code you show won't crash on its own if your internet connection stops working. (Unless the system is killing your app for taking too long, in which case you have little choice but to use some kind of async method or move this to a background thread.)

Comment: try to NSLog("Error: %@",[error description]); and see whats the error.

Comment: Like @JesseRusak said, you can not want to use async networking, but there's a good chance that if you don't, the watchdog can kill your app in a situation like this.

Comment: I got it. if there is no internet connection, then response variable will be nil. I can check that `if (response == nil)` and give my alert here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. if there is no internet connection, then response variable will be nil. I can check that `if (response == nil)` and give my alert here.